# Do we need different events for each layout?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

My rendered method is being called before _initializeLayout:

```
var _initializeLayout = function() {

    console.log('initializeLayout...');

    Controller.layout = new Layout();

        Controller.layout.on("show", function() {

        vent.trigger("layout:rendered");

    });

    vent.trigger('app:show', Controller.layout);

};
```

I use the layout in the on rendered method:

```
// controller attach a sub view/ search View
vent.on("layout:rendered", function() {
    console.log('layout:rendered =>StartController');

    // render views for the existing HTML in the template, and attach it to the layout (i.e. don't double render)
    var inspectorStartView = new InspectorStartView();
    Controller.layout.inspector.attachView(inspectorStartView);

    var playerStartView = new PlayerStartView();
    Controller.layout.player.attachView(playerStartView);
});
```

When I try it, my on rendered callback is called before _initializeLayout().  I have it calling  _initializeLayout in the router/controller method:

```
Controller.go_inspector_control_center = function(term) {
        _initializeLayout();
        //vent.trigger("search:term", term);
    };
```

I just ran it again and found that an event was being triggered from a different controller's _initializeLayout() method:

```
   // private
var _initializeLayout = function() {
    console.log('initialize Start Layout...');
    Controller.layout = new Layout();
    Controller.layout.on("show", function() {
        **vent.trigger("layout:rendered"); // <--**
    });
    vent.trigger('app:show', Controller.layout);
};
```

It appears that the events need to have unique names.  I'll try that.  If anyone knows please chime in.

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't take us Java guys anywhere.  The answer (in Javascript) is that I do need to name my events uniquely.  Makes sense when you think about it.

Although most event systems I've worked with X11/Java you don't name your event you use what they give you.

Here is a [stackoverflow question on event naming.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450397/javascript-event-naming-conventions)

I hope my public learning is helping others. ;-)

Comment: This example is from Mr. Marionette himself:  MyApp.vent.on("some:namespaced:event", function(){
  // do stuff
});
with this example it looks like you create your own namespace but the event on the right end is an event name. The "namespace"  == some.namespaced and you can come up with what you want
MyApp.vent.trigger("some:namespaced:event");